# Retrieve datas signed with RSA?

Tags: c#

I am developing an app that have to communicate with a server and here is the problem.

When I connect to the server the server first send me a HELLOMessage containing a 1024 bit rsa public key signed with a 2048 bit rsa private key.

I have in my data the 2048 bit public key corresponding to the server’s private key, so what I want is to verify the data in the message to retrieve the little public key.

But in c# RSACryptoServiceProvider only contains methods to verify by comparing a hash or verify directly with raw data. There is no method to just verify and retrieve the previously signed data ?

Hope someone could help !
Thanks

Edsdev

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.verifydata?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Absolutely not what I want, returns a bool by comparing hashes not returning the unsigned data.

Comment: You first verify the signature and then decrypt, there's no single method to do both

Comment: I was not clear so I try to explain better way. Here is my understanding of signature using RSA, someone use a private jet to sign a hash , then another people use public to retrieve the hash et compare with the message hash to ensure data wasn’t edited. What I want is like verifying signature by retrieving the hash but not compare it like Microsoft functions but just retrieving the hash and then I will use it for différend other things ... Do you have an idea ?